# How to automatically resolve an id to a model instance in a Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5 (dev / master) is it possible to have laravel auto load the DI Eloquent model with an id? Something similar to Symfony 2 annotation.

```
class MyController {
  public function show($id, MyModel $model) {
      // I'm hoping $model->id == $id if it exists
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it is called [Route Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding).

In your `RouteServiceProvider::before` method, use `$router->model` to set it up:

```
public function before(Router $router, UrlGenerator $url) {
    $router->model('user', 'User');
}
```

Then, whenever you have a parameter named `user`, it will automatically be replaced with an instance of `User`.

Comment: anyway to do this through annotations in laravel 5 like symfony @ParamConverter annotation?

Comment: I don't think so. If there was, I believe it would be at least mentioned in the documentation.